# Parsed json data includes question text and image

Tags: json, parsing, swift4

I have built out a struct and am correctly parsing JSON data and am getting the data to show up with one exception. The text I am getting also includes a URL string. How do I parse both the text and URL image?

Here is the example of the data:

```
"text": "<p>How would you rate your knowledge about investing in general and more specifically, the relationship between risk and return as shown in this chart?</p>\r\n\r\n<p>\r\n<img src=\"https://services.website.com/Charts/$versions/2180/2180.png\" />\r\n</P>\r\n"
```

I have a label called question text that the text is being parsed into. Do I need to add a UIImage to below the text label? The problem I am thinking with this is that on some questions I have text then an image, then more text.

Comment: is the HTML above what you're getting or what you're generating?  I don't quite understand.  That HTML is a combination of text and inline images; splitting out into separate JSON fields is not going to be exactly the same.  What is your goal with converting this to JSON?

Comment: @Joe This is what I am getting. My goal is to show the text and the image.

Comment: This is really more a question about parsing HTML, which is a different thing than just reading the field in the JSON.  And more subjective, since there's some context around the HTML that I'm not sure others will understand with the current info provided.  What is your goal with the embedded HTML?  What are you converting it into?

Comment: the data is from an api. I am parsing the data and displaying it in text label for the text and for the image want to display it as a uiimage. The text is parsing fine but the image doesn't come through. What I want to know is how do I parse the image when its inline with text as a string. Can it even be done?

Comment: I think you should look into [SwiftSoup](https://github.com/scinfu/SwiftSoup) for parsing html and extracting the link to the image. Then of course you need to download the image

Comment: I was thinking of doing it as an NSTextAttachment. I am playing around with that now and will post my findings.